# Automatically install toolbarbutton to firefox nav-bar, not working with insertItem

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

So I've read just about everything I could find on MDN, stackoverflow, etc, and it all seems to be outdated and/or not working.  Here is the issue:

I want to automatically put my extension's "toolbarbutton" on the nav-bar when it is installed, similar to Chrome.  What the user does after that point is up to them, although if you remove the button (with this particular extension) you might as well just remove the extension as it's useless without the button.  ANYWAY...

There seems to be two methods for doing this.  You can append it to the "currentSet" and make it persist, like this:

```
var currentset = document.getElementById("nav-bar").currentSet;
currentset=currentset + ",MYBUTTON_ID";
document.getElementById("nav-bar").setAttribute("currentset",currentset);
document.getElementById("nav-bar").currentSet = currentset;
document.persist("nav-bar","currentset");
```

Or, you can use "insertItem" like this:

```
var toolbar = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
toolbar.insertItem("MYBUTTON_ID", null);  
toolbar.setAttribute("currentset", toolbar.currentSet);  
document.persist(toolbar.id, "currentset");
```

Now, if I use the first method, it works, but it completely erases everything else on the nav bar for some reason.  "currentSet" doesn't seem to have the other nav-bar buttons on it when it goes to overwrite it, and so I just end up with the default nav-bar plus my icon.  Wiping out all of a user's other buttons is no good...

The second option doesn't wipe out the other options, but for whatever reason, the "insertItem" way of doing it doesn't work at all.  My button never appears in the nav-bar, period.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add your button to the palette?

Comment: The <toolbarbutton> is nested inside of the <toolbarpalette> with id "BrowserToolbarPalette"

Comment: No one has any idea?  Really? :(

Comment: The code as you have it here seems correct - I use similar code (with `insertItem`) and it works fine. Maybe the issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, like I thought, there was nothing wrong with my code, and the problem was exactly as I described.

**When the extension is loaded and the script to install the button is executed, it's done too early.  At the time of execution, "currentSet" only contains the default buttons.  No other extension buttons are loaded yet.  As a result, if you modify the currentSet and save (persist) it, you wipe out all other buttons.**

The solution (for me) was to force my "install" script to wait longer.  I found that once the page had been loaded, all of the other buttons had enough time to appear.  So, I simply did this:

```
function installButton() {

    var navbar = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
    var newset = navbar.currentSet + ",MYBUTTONID";
    navbar.currentSet = newset;
    navbar.setAttribute("currentset", newset );
    document.persist("nav-bar", "currentset");

}

window.addEventListener("load", function () { installButton(); }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

well I use this code to add toolbar button in `navbar`, but this works only for the first time for the fresh installation and not for the next installation i.e. upgrading of the addon as user can move/drag the icon to different location. So, you need to try this in the new [firefox profile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Command_Line_Options#User_Profile). Here is the code:

```
//plcae toolbar icon
var navbar = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
var newset = navbar.currentSet + ",MYBUTTON_ID";
navbar.currentSet = newset;
navbar.setAttribute("currentset", newset );
document.persist("nav-bar", "currentset");
```

and here is the code for XUL Overlay:

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
<toolbarbutton id="MYBUTTON_ID" inserbefore="searchBar" class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional"
    label="MYBUTTON_ID" tooltiptext="MYBUTTON_ID"
    onclick="MYBUTTON_ID()"/>
</toolbarpalette>
```

or **you can force** the icon to display in nav bar against user will, this will take effect after each firefox restart, however not recommended

```
var navbar = document.getElementById("nav-bar");

    var newset = navbar.currentSet;
    if (newset.indexOf("MYBUTTON_ID") == -1)
    {
        if (newset.indexOf("reload-button,stop-button,") > -1)
            newset = newset.replace("reload-button,stop-button,", "reload-button,stop-button,MYBUTTON_ID,");
        else
            newset = newset + ",MYBUTTON_ID";
        navbar.currentSet = newset;
        navbar.setAttribute("currentset", newset );
        document.persist("nav-bar", "currentset"); 
    }
```

Comment: I will try this later today and let you know how it goes.  Thank you for responding, I really appreciate it.

Comment: So both of the options you described above wipe out the other extension buttons a user may have installed (at least in my browser).  For example, if I have firebug next to the home button, then install my extension, the button appears, but firebug is gone.  This is because for whatever reason, at the time my extension is executed, the "currentset" doesn't have the other buttons in it yet.  So you're essentially adding the button to a default current set, and then by "persisting" it, you overwrite and wipe out anything else.

Comment: make sure you are not missing any comma "," in currentset. Can you post your new code snippet here?

Comment: My code is a direct copy paste of the above.  The issue isn't about commas.  If in my extension I put "alert(navbar.currentSet)" and it actually shows what is in the currentSet when my extension loads up, none of the other buttons (like firebug) are in the currentSet.  It's only the default firefox buttons (navigation, home, etc).  So when you append my button to the currentset and save it (persist), now the currentSet is saved without the other buttons in it, and they never show up.